# Xpages radio btn group checked

Tags: radio-button, xpages, checked

I can't find a way to set the checked value to a radio button to true... Is there a way, that one radio button to be always checked when the XPage is loaded?

Thanks,

Florin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Radio Button control, there is a selectedValue and defaultSelected properties. As long as selectedValue is set - it doesn't matter what it's set to - then if defaultSelected="true" it will be always selected when the XPage is loaded.

For a Radio Button group, you just need to set the defaultValue property to one of the values defined on the Values tab.