# setting checked value of a Radio Button Group server Side

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

In a repeat (var=row, indexVar=rownumber) ,I can't get the the defaultselected to work . The return value becomes correctly "true" but doesn't work.

The idea is that 1 radio from this radiogroup ("selection") is preselected, based on the value in the viewScope selectie.

```
<xp:radio id="radio1" value="#{viewScope.test}" groupName="selection">
            <xp:this.text><![CDATA[#{javascript:row[3]}]]>
            </xp:this.text>                                                     
       <xp:this.defaultSelected><![CDATA[#{javascript:var check = "no";
         try{
           for (i=0;i<25;i++){
             if( @IsMember(row[4],viewScope.selectie[0][i])==1){var 
             check="true";break}//only 1 can be checked
           }//end for i
          if (check=="true"){return true}
          else {return false}
        }//end try
        catch (e){
          sessionScope.error = "error radio1 :"+e.toString();}}]]>
    </xp:this.defaultSelected>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" 
     refreshId="resultPanel">
         <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var item 
             =viewScope.lijnknr.intValue();
             viewScope.selectie[0].set(item,row[4]);}]]>
         </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:radio>
```

**EDIT**
I added following line : `<xp:this.selectedValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:row[4]}]]></xp:this.selectedValue>`
since I read following post : [Xpages radio btn group checked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25601434/1302906)

but it still doesn't work .....

**SECOND EDIT**
added another property : skipContainers="1" as found in "Mastering Xpages",

but still doesn't work ....

Comment: Isn't there a typo in the SSJS for defaultSelected? Shouldn't `@IsMember` search for `row[4]` in `viewScope.selectie[0]` instead of `viewScope.selectie[0][i]`? Also, IMO the whole code for this property could be simplified to `return (@IsMember(row[4],viewScope.selectie[0]) ? true : false)` .

Comment: No, it's not a typo. viewScope.selectie is an array, and row[4] can be at one of the 25 positions in this array.

Comment: Then why do you iterate with `@IsMember`? if `viewScope.selectie` already is the array that does or does not contain the value `row[4]`, the code for defaultSelected should just be `#{javascript:return (@IsMember(row[4],viewScope.selectie)==1 ? true : false);}` .

Comment: You're right , I changed it to (@IsMember(row[4],viewScope.selectie[0])==1 ? true : false); , since the array selectie has two "levels" . This way the code is better, but the result is the same. The problem remains : the defaultSelected property becomes true for the correct radio , but the radio isn't checked. Is their another way to select the radio , for example change the style of the "preselected" radio ?

Comment: For example ; when I put (@IsMember(row[4],viewScope.selectie[0])==1 ? "color:red" : "");  in the computed style property of the radio, the text of defaultchecked radio becomes red . But how do I change the style in order to not change its color to red but select it ...... ?

Comment: I never use radio or radioGroup elements, but I think the problem might be that you set the value of the radio element to `viewScope.test` and thus defaultSelected might not apply anymore. Also, instead of using a repeat control with single radio elements, I recommend using the approach with the radioGroup element that has been suggested by @shillem in his answer below.

Comment: I removed viewScope;.test as value of the radioGroup an , it's working now!
Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach, if possibile, is to to use the `radioGroup` component:

```
<xp:radioGroup value="#{viewScope.fruit}" defaultValue="orange">
    <xp:selectItems value="#{javascript:['apple', 'orange', 'banana']}" />
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        execMode="partial" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="result" />
</xp:radioGroup>

<xp:div id="result">
    <xp:text value="The selected fruit is: #{empty viewScope.fruit ? 'none' : viewScope.fruit}" />
</xp:div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**IMPORTANT EDIT!**

*What I wrote below stands if the radios were declared one by one - therefore outside the repeat component. When placed inside the repeat component there's a bug that prevents the radio group from working as one. In fact, the output `name` param results different for every looped radio component...*

---

I don't see your whole code there so I will go with an example.
Consider the following (and for brevity's sake I will commit this sin of using SSJS sometimes):

```
<xp:repeat value="#{javascript: ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']}"
    var="fruit">
    <xp:radio groupName="fruits" selectedValue="#{fruit}"
        value="#{viewScope.fruit}" defaultSelected="#{fruit eq 'orange'}" text="#{fruit}" />
</xp:repeat>
```

I passed an on-the-fly array to the repeat control and I will reference each value as `fruit`.

At this point I populate the radio component:

1. I used the same `groupName` to group the radios (this you know)
2. I assigned the `selectedValue` to the current `fruit`. This is the value that will be saved if the radio gets selected
3. I bound `value` to the property where the selected value will actually be saved (in this case, like you did, I went for the `viewScope`)
4. I set the `defaultSelected` value (evaluated from the literal value **orange** but you can do it differently). In case `viewScope.fruit` is empty **orange** will be the default value.
5. I assigned the `text` - label - again to the current `fruit` variable

Again, this will give you the **orange** choice as default selection in case the variable `viewScope.fruit` is empty. If, supposedly, you had assigned a value to the viewScope during page load like, say:

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" beforePageLoad="#{javascript: viewScope.fruit = 'banana'}">
```

Then the selected radio would not have been **orange** but **banana**.

Regarding the `eventHandler`, it's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve there. If you want to further explain maybe I can help there also.

Comment: The radios are declared in the repeat. So probably the bug will be the problem. They seem to act as one , since when you select an item , the previously selected one is deselected.The way I'm using it now works except the "preselection".Isn't it possible to solve this with css. (change the style to a selected state when the radio should be selected) I'm not really into css , so I don't know what's possible ...